# simple transparent background compatibility question

Tags: css, lightbox

Would the following code in a CSS class be fully compatible with all the common browsers?

`background:#000;
    -moz-opacity:.50; filter:alpha(opacity=50); opacity:.50`

I'm just wondering if I should use this or a translucent gif to achieve a lightbox style effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you should use translucent `gif` or `png` to achieve this type of effects as far as it is possible. Because only modern browser support css3 specifications as this is not yet a CSS standard.

Answer (score 0):

I think IE6 (maybe even IE7?) are not compatible with alpha opacity filter. For backward compatibility you should stick to a transparent image.

I would try your method first, then check for old browsers compatibility and in case switch to a transparent image.